# Using functions that require roles for permissions within services

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've got a number of services, and each service has a number of functions. Pretty much each function requires a certain 'role' that the current user needs to execute it.

Is there a better way than putting the following code at the beginning of each method? It would be neat if I could just decorate these methods with Attributes, but I'm not sure how I can apply them here.

```
public void CreateTruck(TruckDto dto)
{
    var currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
    if (!currentUser.Can("CreateTruck"))
        throw PermissionException("...");

    // otherwise proceed normally
}
```

Comment: If only it were possible to inject code by using attributes...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I see this happening:

1 - You don't change anything, or simply make that an easy one liner:

```
EnsureUserCan("CreateTruck");
```

Which internally has this method call:

```
protected void EnsureUserCan(string role)
{
    if(!GetCurrentUser().Can(role))
       throw PermissionException("...");
}
```

2 - You move to an invoker pattern:

```
var myNewTruck = ServiceInvoker.Invoke<TruckService>(x => x.CreateTruck(dto));

public class ServiceInvoker
{
    public ReturnType Invoke<ServiceType, ReturnType>(Expression<Func<ServiceType, ReturnType>> methodExpression)
    {
        // blah blah
        var myService = IoC.Resolve<ServiceType>();

        return methodExpression.Compile()(myService); // etc
    }
}
```

And your invoke method inspects the expression for attributes and thus can throw the exception based on an attribute. That seems like overkill though.